# Can't install PackageProvider on NanoServer

Tags: windows-nano-server

I installed a new NanoServer as a VM. Now i want to install some roles online with the NanoServerPackage.

When i fire `Install-PackageProvider NanoServerPackage` I get the Error

```
WARNING: The specified PackageManagement provider 'NuGet' is not available. 
Install-PackageProvider : No match was found for the specified search criteria 
for the provider 'NanoServerPackage'. The package provider requires 
'PackageManagement' and 'Provider' tags. 
Please check if the specified package has the tags.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (Microsoft.Power...PackageProvider:InstallPackageProvider) [Install-PackageProvider], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoMatchFoundForProvider,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.InstallPackageProvider
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that the latest version 2.8.5.206 of NuGet Provider is not compatible with TP5 version of Nano Server. We have rolled it back to the old version, 2.8.5.205.
You need to manually delete NuGet folder under

$env:ProgramFiles\PackageManagement\ReferenceAssemblies
$env:LOCALAPPDATA\PackageManagement\ProviderAssemblies
And relaunch the PowerShell. Sorry for the inconvenience.